# Android SmsMessage country code

Tags: android, sms, pdu

I'm currently working on a app to blacklist SMS from a specific country, I already created my BroadcastReceiver class, which start a service to compare the phone number to the ones stored in the database.
My database contains mobile country code, and I would like to compare the received country code to those in the database, unfortunately I didn't find any method to retrieve the country code from the number. I thought that I could retrieve it with a simple substring call, but I noticed that not all the country codes are the same length, so I couldn't do this like that.
I was wondering if the prefixes were unique (that is to say if a prefix could be the prefix of another), if no, then could I start by taking the maximum size prefix and then a shorter prefix and so on ?
Could you give me a hint on how to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Can u not just take the suffix out? I would think that all phone numbers are eight digits long, that would leave the country code left in the string.

Comment: Not all the numbers are heights digit long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phone number rules are rather complicated and there are many special cases. To extract country code reliably, I'd suggest to use a specialized library. There's a well-known library from Google, called libphonenumber:

https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Take a look at extractCountryCode method from PhoneNumberUtil, or PhoneNumberUtil.parse which returns a PhoneNumber object on which you can call getCountryCode.

It's open source, so, alternatively, if you don't want to mess with additional libraries, you can take a look at its implementation for hints on how to handle country codes by yourself.

Comment: Thank you the extractCountryCode was really helpful, and I'm quite happy because I created a function that looked exactly the same.